# jQuery working in Console but not working in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following jQuery code in the search bar of my website. Since I am a beginner, I am unable to relate to other code examples, hence I need help in fixing the code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //Open Link in Search Results in New Window
    jQuery('div.search_result_item_content').click(function () {
        console.log("I am executed");
        var menuLink = $('div.col.col-9.search_result_item_content').data('link');
        window.open(menuLink, "_blank");
    });
});
```

The code without `.ready()` seems to work on the console. But not on the index.js file of my website. The same file has many other jQuery functions, which are all working smoothly.

Any idea, what is causing the issue?

Comment: Start by removing `<script src='https://c0.wp.com/c/5.4.1/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'></script> ` and move `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` up to the top of the head. Then remove the migrate and fix the errors

Comment: Please see the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552), where the answer is no. Show all relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: Also there is no `search_result_item_content` on the page when it loads so you need to delegate

Comment: @NirmalKumar well it's your first post no issue but before posting any question just read the FAQ and you should provide code or more detail, not your website.

Comment: @Adityatoke I will definitely follow it from my next question.

Comment: @NirmalKumar cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating the items dynamically so this will not work. What you can do is what I will do below.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {   
    jQuery(document).on('click','div.search_result_item_content',function () {
    console.log("I am executed");
    var menuLink = $(this).data('link');
    window.open(menuLink, "_blank");
 });
```

That should work for you.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Just the closing brackets are missing.

Comment: You didnt vote the answer

Comment: I tried voting. I am a new user. It received a notification that votes cast by users with a reputation of less than 15 are not recorded.